# how to find the frequency of marks each mark from 0 to total marks in a tuple

Tags: python, list, loops, tuples

A teacher is in the process of generating few reports based on the marks scored by the students of her class in a project based assessment.
Assume that the marks of her 10 students are available in a tuple. The marks are out of 25.

Write a python program to implement the following functions:
find_more_than_average(): Find and return the percentage of students who have scored more than the average mark of the class

sort_marks(): Sort the marks in the increasing order from 0 to 25. The sorted values should be populated in a list and returned

generate_frequency(): Find how many students have scored the same marks. For example, how many have scored 0, how many have scored 1, how many have scored 3….how many have scored 25. The result should be populated in a list and returned.

i got the average and sorted parts correct.but for the frequency,  if the element is repeated twice i got the frequency as 1

```
list_of_marks=(12,18,25,24,2,5,18,20,20,21)

def find_more_than_average():
    sumi=0
    count=0
    sumi=sum(list_of_marks)
    avg=sumi/len(list_of_marks)
    for i in list_of_marks:
        if(i>avg):
            count=count+1
    morethanavg=(count/len(list_of_marks))*100
    return morethanavg


    #Remove pass and write your logic here

def sort_marks():
    return sorted(list_of_marks)
    #Remove pass and write your logic here

def generate_frequency():
    #Remove pass and write your logic here
    gener=[]
    for i in range(0,26):
        if i in list_of_marks:
            gener.append(1)
        else:
            gener.append(0)
    return gener


print(find_more_than_average())
print(generate_frequency())
print(sort_marks())
```

expected-[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
actual-[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
if i in list_of_marks:
   gener.append(1)
else:
   gener.append(0)
```

it should be clear that you can never get a value other than 0 or 1. But you want the counts of those values not just a 1 indicating the value is in the list. One options is to create a list of zeros first, then step through the marks and add one to the index corresponding to the mark:

```
def generate_frequency():
    gener = [0] * 26
    for m in list_of_marks:
        gener[m] += 1
    return gener
```

Now when you see 20 twice you will increase `generator[20]` twice with the result:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
```